# mysql before insert trigger does not work when trying to insert a new row

Tags: mysql

I created a `Before Insert` MySQL trigger to check if few values already exists on the table, but the trigger is not working.

This is my trigger:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER TEST1
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON roles FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    DECLARE atExists INT DEFAULT 0;
    SELECT count(id) FROM roles WHERE personal_id = NEW.personal_id  AND role = NEW.role AND favorite = New.favorite INTO atExists;
    IF (atExists = 0) THEN INSERT INTO roles (personal_id, role, favorite) VALUES (NEW.personal_id, NEW.role, NEW.favorite);
    END IF;
END $$;
DELIMITER;
```

I have a row that has for example values:
999999999, "admin", "abcde"

and when I try to do

```
INSERT INTO roles (personal_id, role, favorite) values (999999999, "admin", "abcde");
```

After running the trigger, it does adds the new row even though it should just skip it.

I tried with IF NOT EXISTS (...) etc, did not work.
I also checked the SELECT to see if it does find the existing rows and it does.

Comment: Your trigger **MUST** fail due to SELECT in it (you must use SELECT INTO). And even when you fix this then it must fail due to INSERT in it (you cannot insert in the same table).

Comment: Thanks, I forgot to add the INTO, but then, how can I insert the item in the same table? Should I create a temporary table (copy of roles) and check on it?

Comment: There can be no operations on the table that fire/invoke the trigger. What you have would be considered a recursive definition that is not allowed. Think about it ... an insert fires the trigger, then the trigger definition has an insert that would fire _yet another_ trigger, and so on. I don't believe a trigger is needed for whatever you're trying to do. Sounds like composite unique index may be a better way to avoid whatever duplicates that you're trying to avoid.

Comment: Consider a compound unique key on personal_id, role, favorite which will discard attempted duplicates.